Mechanical (viscoelastic) analog of an $RC$ circuit lattice network with a DC voltage source
physics stack exchange.
I am an electrical / power system engineering student who is conducting a research on complex systems; to be precise, an RC circuit lattice network with a DC voltage source, which size can be very large. As you can see below, a "bond" consists of a resistor and a capacitor connected in series.
I want to find a mechanical/viscoelastic analog to the circuit. My circuit network should represent disordered solid. Each bond, as a single "module", should be represented by the equivalent system consisted of mechanical/viscoelastic components, while the equivalent quantities of voltage, current, power must be found for analysis purpose. I don't actually want to "solve" the analogous system, but demonstrate in my research a point.
A spring used as an analog to a capacitor seems inappropriate for my particular case. A bond may be removed throughout a simulation and when one end of the bond is not connected to any bond (so called a dangling node's bond), the capacitor in that bond does not dissipate energy and the potential difference is constant throughout the remaining simulation. However, a spring would, if I understood correctly, dissipate energy while a quantity equivalent to its potential difference decreases.
EDIT In my actual model, each "major" node (that isn't on the busbars and the middle of a bond) have 4 bonds connected (periodic boundary condition imposed). My simulation involves removing one bond sequentially during both transient and "steady" state. As my simulation continues, there are some occasions in which, for one "major" node, 3 bonds have been removed. When the third bond is removed, the remaining 4th bond becomes the dangling node's bond, and no current flows. Whether the 3rd bond was removed during transient or steady state, no current should flow in the 4th bond immediately after the removal of the 3rd bond. The charge and the potential difference across the capacitor remain constant, too.
If this is not that trivial (like if it involves some heavy math stuffs like fractional calculus), I want to identify the depth of this problem, at least. Or, I want to find the mechanical/viscoelastic analog of an resistor-only case, where all capacitors are replaced by short circuit in my network.

A little background to my RC network: the smallest, nontrivial network of my study is drawn above (without periodic boundary condition imposed). Disorder is introduced (independently) to both Capacitance and Resistance, while all capacitors are uncharged initially. Note that a DC voltage source is applied to the circuit network: we assume that, for $t\leq0$, we ignore the capacitive behavior of the network and only the resistive behavior is considered. Hence, initial condition of this dynamic system is solved easily with just an equivalent, resistor-only network, while we can effectively remove the impulse behavior at $t=0$. (I don't know how to better phrase this, but this is not the main part. I welcome any of your advice!) The direction of current $I_{V_0}$ is intentional. I am not using SPICE, I wrote codes from scratch that involves discretization (backward Euler method) of matrix differential equations and sparse LU decomposition using SuperLU to solve nodal voltages at given $t$. Note that even the simplest circuit presented in this post practically impossible to be solved analytically by hands and feet or symbolic calculator.
Thanks for taking your time reading this!
First attempt, I've tried to find an analog of very simple circuit: a voltage source, a capacitor and a resistor all connected in series. The equation is given by removing the inductor, or the mass in this video. It gives me $v(t) = R\cdot i(t) + \frac{1}{C} \int i(t)dt \Leftrightarrow \int f(t) dt = b \int \dot{x}(t) dt  + K \int x(t) dt$. I'm not sure what this represents visually, and if this can be applied to each bond accurately. The indefinite integral is another thing to be figured out, too.
Initially, I thought each bond can be modeled using Maxwell model, where a damper and a spring are connected in series. But, I think it neither is an exact analog nor leads to a consistency when matching stress, strain, strain rate, etc. to the circuit quantities. When I googled, there is a lack of information about series connected resistor and capacitor as opposed to a parallel connected one. I've seen people using Kelvin/Voigt model for parallelly connected pairs of a resistor and a capacitor. This is equivalent to one layer of vertical bonds in my case, and I'm not sure if I can just plainly use this.
Second attempt I'm not sure why, but based on this video and my pattern recognition, a capacitor can be modeled as a damper (dashpot) and a resistor can be modeled as a spring.
$$\text{Damper - Capacitor: } \sigma(t) = \eta \frac{d \varepsilon (t)}{dt} \Leftrightarrow i(t) = C\frac{d v(t)}{dt}$$
$$\text{Spring - Resistor: } \sigma (t) = k \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow i(t) = G v(t)$$
$$\eta \Leftrightarrow C,\quad k \Leftrightarrow  G,\quad \varepsilon (t) \Leftrightarrow v(t), \quad \sigma(t) \Leftrightarrow v(t)$$
This aligns well with Maxwell model for a resistor and a capacitor in series, too.
$$i_{\text{total}} = i_{\text{capacitor}} = i_{\text{resistor}} \Leftrightarrow \sigma_{\text{total}} = \sigma_{\text{damper}} = \sigma_{\text{spring}}$$
$$v_{\text{total}} = v_{\text{capacitor}} + v_{\text{resistor}} \Leftrightarrow \epsilon_{\text{total}} = \epsilon_{\text{damper}} + \epsilon_{\text{spring}}$$
This is the opposite of almost every papers and information I'd found on internet: spring = capacitor, and damper = resistor. If this is correct, I don't think there is an issue with a dangling node's bond; a damper won't move when the other end is disconnected to the system. However, I'm not sure how to even start interpreting the resistor = spring analogy.

I feel like some of my tags are a bit inappropriate.

Your explanation for why a spring analogy is inappropriate (involving "bonds" being removed) isn't entirely clear.  Are you referring to how certain wire segments can be "cut" in steady state without impacting the state of charge? In an analogous spring-fluid system, wouldn't that just correspond to blocking flow through a particular channel?

Hello, I'm not sure if I've understood the "spring-fluid system" and "blocking flow" correctly, but I certainly do want something like "blocking flow" so that there is no energy flow to the rest of the system. To my understanding, when the "other end" of a spring is disconnected from the rest of the system, it should return to its equilibrium, like how an actual physical spring would in the real world because of Hooke's law. This behavior is not the same as a capacitor, which would not return to its "equilibrium", that is it's initial uncharged state. Also, I have added a paragraph, thanks.

Noted and edited, thanks

It might help to think more carefully about the spring visco-elastic analogy: what exactly is the "viscous" element, for example? (If there is a fluid involved, what conditions are necessary to allow the fluid to flow, and can the spring move if the fluid cannot flow?)

You could imagine the analogous mechanical circuit as a system of springs connected via narrow pipes filled with some kind of lightweight (nearly massless) but incompressible viscous fluid.  In this case, the fluid overdamps the (approximately massless) springs, so they relax in a way that is roughly consistent with the discharge profile of a capacitor.  Breaking the circuit in this case corresponds to blocking a segment of pipe and preventing fluid flow: if you stop one side of a spring, locking the fluid inside, you prevent that side from moving (assuming the fluid is incompressible or nearly incompressible.)  This is exactly analogous to how if you cut off one side of a charged capacitor from the rest of the circuit, you lock the charge in to that side.  Inductors would be analogous to massive weights that are either attached to the springs or are narrow enough that they can fit in the "pipes."
